# Python merging many dataframes by placing closely matching timestamps in same row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have three data frames. Data in each data frame occurs every 30 minutes and all have unique timestamps. 
Some of them have missing data.

```
df1 = 
index                     S1POA

2019-01-09 13:20:17     742.961815
2019-01-09 14:00:17     791.852790
2019-01-09 14:40:17     794.034572
2019-01-09 15:20:17     689.90

df2 = 
index                     S2POA
2019-01-09 13:20:32     734.330740
2019-01-09 14:00:32     803.439840
2019-01-09 14:40:32     804.677047
2019-01-09 15:40:17     567.90

df3 = 
index                     S3POA
2019-01-09 13:20:47     725.699665
2019-01-09 14:00:47     815.026890
2019-01-09 14:40:47     815.319522 
2019-01-09 15:40:47     457.90



biglist3 = [df1,df2,df3] # actually up to df26
```

I would like to take df1 time as a reference, I want to place the data happened during that duration within the same row. For example, the first timestamp is 13:20:17. Data from remaining dfs that happened within 30 mins close to this timestamp should appear in the same row. 
My present code is:

```
l = []
s1 = []
for i in range(0,len(biglist3),1):
    if i==0:
        s1 = biglist3[i]
        l1.append(s1)
    else:            
        l1.append(pd.merge_asof(s1,biglist3[i],left_index=True,right_index=True,direction='nearest'))
combdf = pd.concat(l,axis=1)
```

My present output is

```
index                     S1POA           S2POA          S3POA
2019-01-09 13:20:17     742.961815     734.330740      725.699665
2019-01-09 14:00:17     791.852790     803.439840      815.026890
2019-01-09 14:40:17     794.034572     804.677047      815.319522
2019-01-09 15:20:17     689.90         567.90          457.90
```

My expected output is

```
index                     S1POA           S2POA          S3POA
2019-01-09 13:20:17     742.961815     734.330740      725.699665
2019-01-09 14:00:17     791.852790     803.439840      815.026890
2019-01-09 14:40:17     794.034572     804.677047      815.319522
2019-01-09 15:20:17     689.90         nan             nan         # because df2 and df3 have no data around this time
```

How to rectify my code to get this desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pandas.merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) takes `tolerance` as argument. Two values will be merged within that value. 
As you can see in the page, there is an example with a timedelta, thus your purpose is possible.

You can modify the code as:

```
l1.append(pd.merge_asof(s1,biglist3[i],left_index=True,right_index=True,direction='nearest', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('30s')))
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your code did work. Thanks. I am just curious. What happens when some of the dataframes have no data in that tolerance band?  will they be eliminated?

Comment: I think that such rows will be treated as unique and just appended. It is a wild guess tho, since I never found a case like this.